# How to handle the JSON object with uneven Data in angular 7?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular6, angular7

Service returning the data in this format. I can see the data is coming in the developer tool bar.

```
{"results":{"BindGridDatatable":[{"ID":"0005","Name":"Rohit"}, 
                             {"ID":"0006","Name":"Rahul"}], 
        "Totalvalue":119}}
```

In Component I am receiving in this way

```
 btnSearch(){ 

 this.service.postControlResult(this.myForm.value).subscribe(
  (res: Response)=> {
    this.data = res ;       
   },err => console.error(err)
 );
  }
```

In HTML file I tried multiple ways to show my data like

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let d of data  ">
 {{d.BindGridDatatable.ID}}
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let d of data.BindGridDatatable   ">
 {{d}}
</div>
 </div>
```

I want to bind only BindGridDatatable  to this.data object and Totalvalue I want to store in seperate variable.

I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'BindGridDatatable' of undefined

Comment: try to console your response as `console.log(this.data)`

Comment: In console I can see the same {"results":{"BindGridDatatable":[{"ID":"0005","Name":"Rohit"}, 
                             {"ID":"0006","Name":"Rahul"}], 
        "Totalvalue":119}}

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your result you need to iterate like this -

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let d of data?.results?.BindGridDatatable">
    {{d?.ID}} - {{d?.Name}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

> PS: The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

And mostly used in async call data binding where on the initial stage variable value is null or undefined to avoid such issues we use safe navigation operator `?`

For more in details about `?`

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 2):

Your response is an object and not an array.
 So use,

```
let d of d.results.BindGridDatatable
```

in the ngfor

Comment: I am getting this error: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Comment: Then try data?.results?.BindGridDatatable

Comment: use safe navigation operator like I mentioned in my answer `?`

Comment: Can you please upvote and accept my answer as I have answered first.

Comment: @dileepkumarjami brother yes you answered first, but not exact answer what he wants. Please keep in mind always test before posting answer :) +1

Comment: @PardeepJain, Thanks for editing my answer. I answered from my mobile and hence I could not format it properly. Using d.results.BindGridDatatable  is the solution. As he has not posted the complete code, I donno when is the data populated. So he had to use the safe navigation operator

Comment: @dileepkumarjami NP man, keep coding and sharing knowldege :)